# How to handle "javascript out of memory exception" Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to read 60 million records from MySql DB, need to update the date column every day based on some calculations, while trying to read from Node.js and Sequelize, it throws **heap out of memory** exception. What is the best way to read, update and recommit?

```
db.sequelize.models.transaction.schema("dpunit").findAll({
    order: [
        ['txndate', 'asc']
    ]
}).then(txnList => {    // txnList have 6million records

let valueUpdated = [];
for (let tranz of txnList) {
  tranz.expdate = new Date() // updated Value
  valueUpdated.push(tranz.dataValues)
}

db.sequelize.models.transaction.schema("dpunit").bulkCreate(valueUpdated, { updateOnDuplicate: ["expdate"] }).then(data => {
                res.send({ data: data.Length });
   }).catch(err => {
       res.send({ error: err});
  });

});
```

Comment: show us how are you doing it, what are the queries being executed and table structure.

Comment: it is a simple table with 4 columns producId, TransactionDate, ExpireyDate, userID, need to update the expireyDate, i'm using simple sequalize findAll() function to read and bulkUpdate() function to update, inbetween loop the data and change the value from the list

Comment: edit your question and show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

From what it seems, the problem lies in bringing all the records in memory. You should use `limit` and `offset` to bring in fewer records and update them in batches
[Limits and Pagination](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-querying-basics/#limits-and-pagination).

If the updation can be done without reading values you should simply run a `update` query and let mysql handle it.

Comment: Is any possible way to do stream? is it recommended?

Comment: I do not know what your use case is, so can't comment on that front.

Comment: my use case is very simple to understand, need to update a column every day, and the table has more than 60million records.